# show eclipse menuContribution in all perspective( not in only plugin development pespective)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have written a plugin that have two menu contribution in project explorer but these menus are visible in only plugin development perspective. I want it to be visible in all perspective (especially in Java and Java EE perspective). Here is my plugin.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI= "popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
         <menu
               icon="icons/sample.gif"
               id="create.exility.project"
               label="Create Exility Project">
            <command
                  commandId="com.exility.plugin.convert"
                  label="Convert into Exility Project"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
       <menuContribution
            locationURI= "popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
         <menu
               id="generate.html.page"
               label="Generate HTML Page">
            <command
                  commandId="com.exility.plugin.CovertIntoHtml"
                  label="Generate HTML"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command

            id="com.exility.plugin.convert"
            name="Convert">
      </command>
      <command

            id="com.exility.plugin.CovertIntoHtml"
            name="CovertIntoHtml">
      </command>
   </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="com.exility.plugin.handler.AddExilityResource"
            commandId="com.exility.plugin.convert">
         <enabledWhen>
            <with
                  variable="activeMenuSelection">
               <count
                     value="1">
               </count>
            </with>
         </enabledWhen>
      </handler>
      <handler
            class="com.exility.plugin.handler.ConvertXMLToHTML"
            commandId="com.exility.plugin.CovertIntoHtml">
         <enabledWhen>
            <with variable="selection">
        <iterate operator="and" ifEmpty="false">
           <test   forcePluginActivation="true"
            property="testWizard.propertyTester.checkFolder"
             value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature">
            </test> 
        </iterate>
     </with>
         </enabledWhen>
      </handler>
   </extension>


   <extension
        point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
     <propertyTester          
        class="testwizard.wizards.MyPropTester"
           id="MyPropTesterFolder"
           namespace="testWizard.propertyTester"
           properties="checkFolder"
           type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
     </propertyTester>

    </extension>

</plugin>
```

Please help me

Comment: Popup context menus contributions should appear on the view regardless of the perspective. You could try doing 'Window > Reset Perspective'.

Comment: Thank you greg...It is appearing in java and Plugin perspective  beacuse of jdt in URI "popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer" it is not appearing in in java ee perspective. But when I Change URI to  "popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions"  then it appears only in Java ee perspective. I think there should be some default URI for all the perspective...Please help..

Comment: That is nothing to do with the perspective, you just have Project Explorer open rather than Package Explorer. If you want the popup in both views add menu contributions using both ids.

Comment: Now I got it...You are really great...thank you very very much.. :)

Comment: I have added an answer summarizing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup (context) menu contributions are not affected by the current perspective.

However different perspectives may be using different views. In this case some perspectives are using the 'Package Explorer' view and others the 'Project Explorer' view. You need to use menu contributions for each view you want the popup to appear in.

Comment: Hi greg, I have posted one question on the below URL..Can you please answer                                                                                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574712/how-to-package-plugin-and-feature-into-osgi-bundle-using-p2-maven-plugin

Comment: I have seen that question, I don't use maven.